# Нетривиальная задачка по SQL

Tags: sql

Есть 2 таблицы:

1. CD c фильмами

Столбцы:

```
| film_id  |  name   |    price  |    
     1       Film A         10
     2       Film B         12
     3       Film C         20
     4       Film D         20
```

2. Таблица жанры

```
| film_id  |  genre
____________________
     1       Comedy         
     2       Horror         
     3       Tragedy         
     4       Comedy
```

Нужно вывести все фильмы в жанре Comedy, которые имеют наибольшую цену.
**НО не использовать при этом Group By, агрегаторы как max и т.п., Order By в комбинации с limit.**

Наверно нужно играться хитро с объединениям. Хз, но мозг уже кипит. Может кто подкинет идею или куда смотреть. Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Сразу напрашивающееся решение:

```sql
SELECT f.*
FROM films f
JOIN genres g USING(film_id)
WHERE g.genre = 'Comedy'
AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                 FROM films f1
                 JOIN genres g1 USING(film_id)
                 WHERE g1.genre = 'Comedy' 
                 /* в общем случае g1.genre = g.genre */
                   AND f.price < f1.price )
```